# How to know our mobile number or phone has been hacked?

Tags: mobile, spoofing

We have a Xiaomi Redmi 2 phone and a sim card in it. Yesterday we started receiving angry and swearing text messages. we called the numbers back and apparently a mass angry text messages have been sent out to random numbers. The sent us the screenshot of the message and our mobile number appears at the header.

We are now wondering if our mobile number was spoofed or the phone was hacked into as there were no trail of that angry text message being sent out.

Is there a was the retrieve the sms log? or find out how was it spoofed?

Comment: speak to your phone service provider

Comment: it is a prepaid mobile number. i dont think there will be a record.

Comment: There will be a record of activity for the number

Comment: You have an android phone, you have much better chance of getting answers on [SE Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com). Check this question for example [how can I get the Call & SMS log for an individual contact?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61470/how-can-i-get-the-call-sms-log-for-an-individual-contact)